# Tools that list the prototypes in .so library

Tags: command-line, libraries

Is there a tool that list the prototypes in a .so library.

I found `nm` close to my need, but what I got are just symbols.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't, because the prototypes are not stored in the library; they go in the header file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [objdump](http://linux.die.net/man/1/objdump) :

```
objdump -T -C libfoo.so
```

- -T stands for dynamic symbols
- -C will help making c++ methods more human-friendly

Comment: That's the same as `nm`